# Graph plotting software that includes the min() and max() functions

Tags: windows-xp, charts

I am looking for online or offline software that can plot functions that include min() and max(). Neither of my favourites, Wolfram Alpha and fooplot seem to have these functions built in :-(

Comment: You wish to plot mathematical functions and determine their extreme values, if I am correct ?

Comment: An example would be to plot y=2*(min(x,300)/300) between x=0 and x=400

Comment: I don't understand the upper syntax. How goes the function that you wish to plot ?

Comment: The min() function comes from C programming (and probably other languages too). min takes two arguments and returns the smaller of the two. So for example min(3,7) would return 3.

Comment: @Mich - Heh. Yes ... I quite understand what is the min or the max function supposed to do :-) There is no problem in that. What I din't understand upon the time of writing the above comment is what was the upper function supposed to plot ? For it is not a typical mathematical syntax nor any that I commonly encountered so far ? At least not without further explanation on it. That's why I asked you to provide a working example ? However, if I understood you correctly you wish ... (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... (continuation from comments) to plot something like this:

[image]

which can simply be plotted from excel. In A column you place a number of points from 0 to 400, and in column B you place `=2*(MIN(A32;300)/300)` ... afterwards you plot both columns on xy plot.